# VS2010 Implement Generic Interface expansion doesn't use specified type

Tags: c#, generics, ide, visual-studio-2010, interface

Using the release version of Visual Studio 2010 I think there's a difference in the "Implement Interface" expansion from VS2008

If I speicify an interface and implement it in a class as so:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IModel
{
    T Get<T>(int id);
    void Update<T>(T item);
    int Add<T>(T item);
}    

public class MockRepository : IRepository<MockUser>
{
// ...
}
```

Then use the "Implement Interface" expansion and get this:

```
public class MockRepository : IRepository<MockUser>
{
    public T Get<T>(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update<T>(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Add<T>(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Instead of what I expected

```
public class MockRepository : IRepository<MockUser>
{
    public MockUser Get<MockUser>(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update<MockUser>(MockUser item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Add<MockUser>(MockUser item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**The IDE uses the type variable name from the generic interface definition `T` instead of the specified concrete type `MockUser`.
Is this a bug? Or is something new just for VS2010 / .Net 4.0?**

**Update:
This is NOT a bug, I didn't specify the interface as I inteded, it should be defined as:**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IModel
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Update(T item);
    int Add(T item);
}
```

in other words I didn't need to specify the Type parameter `T` at the interface and method level, but only at the interface.

Comment: @leppie - have you tried compiling it? I'm still in bed so I haven't, but it looks okay.

Comment: @Daniel who said still being in bed is an excuse to not compile? ; )

Comment: And I'm using a Mac... but then again, it does have Mono installed on it, so you're right, I should really think about my attitude! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no purpose to `<T>` as a type parameter to the interface's methods. It's not necessary, and if you remove it, you'll get the expected behavior -- except that the result is this:

```
public class MockRepository : IRepository<IModel>
{
    public IModel Get(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Add(IModel item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Generic method type parameters are distinct from interface/class type parameters -- I wouldn't expect them to be implemented using `IModel` in your example. (In other words, the T in `IRepository<T>` is not the T in `Get<T>`.)

Comment: In this case, the Idea is that one class may implement many IRepository<T> for many different objects, e.g. IRepository<Foo> and IRepository<Bar>, where each implementation method may need to call distinct data methods, e.g. Get<Foo>(id) may call DB.GetFoo(id) where Get<Bar>(id) may call DB.GetBar(id) this is moslty experimental code and its late so I may be missing something... let me know if that makes sense, and thanks.

Comment: Oh duh! I see now, good catch! I only need it @ the interface level, not at the method level

Comment: Just use T in the method parameters and return values - no need to specify `<T>` for the method declarations.

Comment: @TJB - if Get/Update/Add are suppose to be always using the same type for a given instance of repository, then you don't need to redeclare `<T>` on each method. Right now you're allowing each method to work with any type. **Edit** - okay, you've got it now!

Answer (score 4):

It's doing exactly the right thing for you.

Each of the methods of your interface has its own `T` parameter, which is still unspecified until the caller of the method eventually specifies it. Your interface's `T` is unused.

Comment: Good spot! I didn't notice (in the brief glance) that the methods were *also* generic. I suspect neither did the OP when writing them.